# Postgres alter multiple columns to citext type

Tags: sql, postgresql, alter, column-defaults

We need to change 206 fields in multiple tables to data_type citext (extension). I've created the extension and manually changed a column to see what it should look like in the schema.  The data_type needs to be *USER-DEFINED* and column_default needs to be *''::citext* however I can't get this to work.

```
ALTER TABLE {tablename} ALTER COLUMN data_type USER-DEFINED;

ALTER TABLE {tablename} ALTER COLUMN column_default CONCAT('''','''','::citext');
```

Update 6/15
I was able to successfully update the type with

ALTER TABLE {table_name} ALTER COLUMN {column_name} TYPE citext;

However, I still have a concern that when looking at the properties of the column, under the constraints tab, the Default value is ''::bpchar and not ''::citext like the manuallly change columns.

[image]

Comment: it would be good when you add table definiton of the actual column and and the usertype as well and finally wanted result, from that i can't even guess  what you want to achieve

Comment: That should be *ALTER TABLE {tablename} ALTER COLUMN {column_name} citext;*.  Citext **is the user_defined type** but once created by installing the extension it is used just like any other data type declaration. See the documentation [citext](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/citext.html#id-1.11.7.19.7).

Comment: Thank you both.  Belayer - I've tried this multiple times and it won't accept this change.   ALTER TABLE {table_name} ALTER COLUMN {column_name} citext;

Comment: Sorry, I missed the key word in the alter command. Try *ALTER TABLE {tablename} ALTER COLUMN {column_name} type citext;*.